# PHP - Header authorization request

Tags: php

I need to get data from webservice via PHP, webservice use some header authorization and header should looks like:

```
POST /web/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.web.com:8080
Authorization: Basic TOKEN
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6e8d4551-d984-1a57-589d-25d5816a79b6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=pass&user=admin&pass=admin
```

I tested it via POSTMAN extension to Chrome, and works perfectly!
How ever I try to add things like this to header() I'm getting nowhere, always just downloading blanked files :(

```
header('Host: www.web.cz:8080');
header('Authorization: Basic TOKEN');
header('Accept: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Postman-Token: 6e8d4551-d984-1a57-589d-25d5816a79b6');
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header('grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin');
```

Why it's not getting any response despite the fact header should looks the same?

Comment: `header()` is used to set the headers of a reply, not a request to another API. If you're using `cURL` to send the API request, it has an option to set the headers of the request.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

To add headers to your request you need to set them in the request, header() function sets them in your response.

## Examples

### Curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Host: example.com',
'Accept: application/json'
));
```

### file_get_contents

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

If you use some other method of sending your request, check with documentation.